# Setting the user agent in a Windows Phone 7.1 (SDK 7.1.1) BackgroundTransferRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, user-agent, background-transfer

It's very easy to change the referer by simply setting the appropriate header, however, I cannot find a way to change the user agent ("ZDM/4.0; Windows Mobile 7.0;") to any other value. I tried the following code so far:

```
var request = new BackgroundTransferRequest(new Uri("http://www.somedomain.net"));
request.Headers[Convert.ToString(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent)] = "AgentSmith";
request.Headers[Convert.ToString(HttpRequestHeader.Referer)] = "MyReferer";
```

Any thoughts? Your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Convert.ToString(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent)` returns "UserAgent", but the HTTP Header is "User-Agent"; try the code like this:

```
var request = new BackgroundTransferRequest(new Uri("http://www.somedomain.net"));
request.Headers["User-Agent"] = "AgentSmith";
request.Headers["Referer"] = "MyReferer";
```

Comment: I tried so hard in getting nice and readable code freed from all the hard-coded strings, but totally overlooked the potential problems. Ha! Thank you Pedro.